# Remove the object tag from my html

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to remove the object tag from a text file:

```
    <object classid=""clsid:F08DF954-8592-11D1-B16A-00C0F0283628"" id=""Slider1"" width=""100"" height=""50"">
  <param name=""BorderStyle"" value=""1"" />
  <param name=""MousePointer"" value=""0"" />
  <param name=""Enabled"" value=""1"" />
  <param name=""Min"" value=""0"" />
  <param name=""Max"" value=""10"" />
</object>
```

My regex so far is:

hmtl = Regex.Replace(html, @"]*>(?:.*?)?", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

The inner param tags are not removed.

Comment: You could use the DOM...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify the `<object>` tag as a part of your expression, and match everything to until the `</object>` tag.

```
Regex.Replace(html, @"<object.*?</object>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, this will do it:

```
$line =~ s/<object.*?>.*?<\/object>//is;
```

That's Perl, so the potential quirks:

- ***?*** indicates a non-greedy match, i.e. that it should match the first possible termination of the pattern rather than the last
- ***/i*** is case insensitive
- ***/s*** says to treat the whole text as a single line (to be able to match across line breaks)

Answer (score 0):

This RegEx might work for you (it is very hungry-greedy):

```
<object.+</object>
```

But I would advise to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) instead.
It provides the ability to use HTML's DOM.
So you would work with it just like with XmlDocument:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.htm");
foreach(HtmlNode obj in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("object") {
    obj.Parent.RemoveChild(obj);
}
doc.Save("file.htm");
```